# How do I get the time zone offset (in minutes) from a datetime object?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, iso8601

Does anyone know how to obtain the time zone offset value (in minutes, hrs etc.) of an ISO8601 timestamp? I can see it in a `tzinfo` object, but can't seem to get the value out. Here's what I've done so far, but how do I get the the value -28800 out into a variable?

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> import datetime
>>> firststarttime = '2008-12-31T23:00:00-08:00'
>>> datetime_obj = dateutil.parser.parse(firststarttime)
>>> datetime_obj
datetime.datetime(2008, 12, 31, 23, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -28800))
>>> datetime_obj.tzinfo
tzoffset(None, -28800)
```

Comment: A "time zone" is different from a "time zone offset". The former is something like "Europe/London", whereas the latter is something like "+0100". This is important distinction for various reasons, the most obvious being that time zones can have daylight savings time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use (if you're on Python 2.7 or above):

```
datetime_obj.utcoffset().total_seconds()
```

Using [`utcoffset()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcoffset) to get the `timedelta`, and [`total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) to convert to seconds. You can read the documentation linked for information about what exactly they're doing.

If you need to add this offset onto some other `datetime`, then you can just use `utcoffset()` to get back a `timedelta`. Though the return value might look a bit strange:

```
datetime.timedelta(-1, 57600)  # equivelant to datetime.timedelta(seconds=-28800)
```

This is because of the way `timedelta` normalizes negative values which is also noted at [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, that the values seem to be fixed to that object.
this is not the most efficient way to do it, in fact, I would happily know other answers, but, this is how I'd do it:

```
import dateutil.parser
import datetime
import re
firststarttime = '2008-12-31T23:00:00-08:00'
datetime_obj = dateutil.parser.parse(firststarttime)
s = str(datetime_obj.tzinfo)
p = re.compile(",\s.?\d+")
result = p.search(s).group()
result = int(result[2:])
```

prints

```
print(result)
>>> -28800 # as integer
```